# postgresql :: Operators invalid input syntax for type json

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have some problems  of postgresql .

`select '123456' :: json`
and
`select 123456 ::json` , all of the result is 123456 ;
but `select 'abc' :: json`  result is  `invalid input syntax for type json` .

Is there some statement in official documents?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/datatype-json.html

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.5 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: Maybe you meant `to_json('abc'::text)`?

Answer (score 0):

A JSON string must always be enclosed in double quotes:

```
SELECT '"abc"'::json;
```

I cannot find that explicitly mentioned in the PostgreSQL documentation, but it is clear that only a valid JSON can be cast to `json`.

The [JSON specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259#section-7) documents this:

> The representation of strings is similar to conventions used in the C
> family of programming languages.  A string begins and ends with
> quotation marks.